# If a continuous real function is additive, then it is linear

Tags: calculus, continuity

I have to prove the following problem

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function  such that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y),\ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $f$ is a linear transformation over $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that $f$ is a linear transformation over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I can't pass it to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: f do not must be continuous?

Comment: This is not true in general. Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: Are you assuming linearity over $\mathbb Q$? If not consider function $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ which is continuous and satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ but it's not linear over $\mathbb R$

Comment: Your statement makes no condition for values of $f$ on non-integers.  So it cannot possibly prove that $f$ is linear, even over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

If you can prove that $f$ is linear over $\mathbb{Q}$ then it's easy to see that $f(x) = kx\ \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and because $f$ is continuos then $f(x) = kx\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But we can not prove that $f$ is linear over $\mathbb{Q}$ with these assumptions.

Comment: @user57126  the manoel's question is a good question

Comment: This answer is not useful. The 'if' statement is already impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Uses the continuity, let be $x,y$ and $\alpha$ real numbers,  $(x_n)$ , $(y_n)$ and $(\alpha_n$)  sequences of rational numbers with  $x_n\to x$, $y_n\to y$ and $\alpha_n\to \alpha$ uses the continuity + that you knows about  $f$ be a linear transformation over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e

$$f(\alpha x+y)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\alpha_n x_n+y_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_nf(x_n)+\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y_n)=\alpha f(x)+f(y)$$

Comment: I suppose that $\alpha_n$ should be inside the limit there, or it should be $\alpha$.